# Cборка только требуемых файлов для страницы из шаблона bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, gulp, bower

Приобрел шаблон бутстрапа, в нем по папкам разложены разные стилистические варианты отображения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходим только 1 из них. Более того, всего 1 страница из его состава.
В самой теме очень много лишних файлов, которые не используются на странице, но идут в теме вместе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же предлагается в краткой документации к шаблону, тянуть всю папку плагинов от всех тем, но из нее мне опять же нужно всего пару js которые требуются для страницы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Каким образом я могу собрать только необходимые для страницы файлы?** Пробовал делать это руками, смотря что не подгрузилось в консоли хром, но там выходит большое кол-во файлов различных иконок, css и js, которым нужно соблюсти все пути и вложенности и руками это делать не вариант.

Должно же существовать какое то более простое и компактное решение для минимальной сборки без лишнего хлама и с последующим докидыванием необходимого уже?

проблема не только в less файлах, так же существуют файлы шрифтов различные, файлы скриптов, css для каждого из скриптов. Все они раскиданы по разным папкам, но на самой простой странице используется только минимальный набор, а приходится подключать все и сразу. Лишние скрипты [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
лишние css [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uncss

Comment: я хоть на less стили не собирал но похоже это он https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LESS_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9)

если да то его надо установить (кажетса для этого нужен ruby) и собрать из них css файлы . a js файлов они не делают ибо к оформлению отношения не имеют

Comment: проблема не только в less файлах, так же существуют файлы шрифтов различнstы, файлы скриптов, css для каждого из скриптов. Все они раскиданы по разным папкам, но на самой простой странице используется только минимальный набор, а приходится подключать все и сразу.

Лишние скрипты http://www.imghost.in/img/2017-08/11/s8a8pi3vwclaetepcez3fd05t.png
лишние css http://www.imghost.in/img/2017-08/11/v37w50pebkikzkgk5gucrua2s.png

Answer (score 0):

Привет! Если я правильно понял твой вопрос, то вот ответ на него https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OfWdTYCJC0U